# Laravel 5.5 - whereIn and whereNotIn in same eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two tables where I need to `pluck` the valid building ids (those that match the `$buildingIds` array) that exist in `buildings` AND must ensure they don't already exist in `buildings_built` (so we know which buildings need to be built). It can be done in two queries easily, but I am trying to do it with a single query to be more efficient:

```
$buildingIds = ['a1','b2','c3'];

Tables
// buildings       (id, building_name)    (a1, adam)  (b2, barney)  (c3, castor) 
// buildings_built (id, building_id)       (1, a1)     (2, b2)
```

Here is my attempt at this that doesn't work properly:

```
$buildingsToBuildFromIdsArray = Buildings::whereIn('buildings.id', $ids)
                                 ->whereNotIn('buildings_built.building_id', $ids)
                                 ->pluck('buildings.id');
```

Ideally, the query should return `['c3']`, since that building exists in `buildings` table and does **not** exist in `buildings_built` table (has not been built yet).

Any idea how to get it to work correctly?

Comment: You'll need to `->join(...)` them first. Then the query should work.

Comment: @devk I tried joining on the id/building_id but it's an empty array

Comment: How are the tables related? If they're not related at all, you won't be able to join them.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear initially, I improved the question to be more practical, but there is no relations set up at the moment. I would also be open to doing it with `DB::` instead of the model directly if it's easier in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to create a relationship between two models - I will work with the default naming for models as `Building` and `Build`:

```php
class Building extends Model
{
    public function builds(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Build::class, 'building_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Build extends Model
{
    public function building(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Building::class, 'id', 'building_id');
    }
}
```

To fetch your records you could then use the `doesntHave` query builter method

```php
Building::whereIn('id', $ids)->doesntHave('builds')->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear initially, I improved the question to be more practical, but there is no relations set up at the moment. I would also be open to doing it with `DB::` instead of the model directly if it's easier in a single query.

Comment: I've updated my answer - I kept model names as singulars, but feel free to update it as you're pleased.

Comment: This is actually a really nice solution. Except, if I understand correctly, you want `->doesntHave(..)` instead of `->whereHas(..)`. Other than that, this should get you what you want.

Comment: Basically, you want to set up your models and the relationships, like Sebastian suggested and do this query: `Building::whereIn('id', $ids)->doesntHave('builds')->pluck('id')`

Comment: @SebastianSulinski Thank you for the relations, they work now using @devk query in the comment. I really like the `->doesntHave('builds')` portion, that's pure genius @devk! Just to add, if another `where` clause is needed with `doesntHave` just turn it to a closure but change it to `whereDoesntHave` instead. Otherwise `doesntHave` will not work with the closure `where`. Thank you both so much for the help, you guys are awesome :)

Comment: Apologies - I was writing this late at night - thanks for updating the code @devk